# formula using string does not work in crystal reports

Tags: vbscript, crystal-reports

I using crystal reports with sql database , 
the problem I wan't to use the join() fonctinality  with a string type and I don't know how . I'am new in crystal reports

this is  my fomula

```
if (hasValue({?User Login})) then join(({?User Login}),",") else "all user are concerned "
```

the error is "A string array is required here (join ()) "

could I forced the type of "user login " to make it a list ??????

NB: User login is dynamic parameter field ( how to change the symbole beside of the parmeter field ???)

Best regards

Comment: change the parameter to select `mutiple value` insetead of `Discrete value`  and use the same formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the parameter to a string using this formula:

```
ToText({?User Login}, 0, "")
```